# JSON object string to convert an array using map

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

Here is my response from my server.

```
var my_array = [{"1":"1"},{"2":"8"},{"4":"13"},{"5":"19"},{"6":"22"}]; //from server
```

I want to convert it like

```
var new_array = { 1 : "1", 2 : "8", 4 : "13", 5 : "19" , 6 : "22"}
```

But how to convert it using **map** function

```
new_array = my_array.map(function (a) {
    return ???
});
```

Comment: You cannot do that via mapping. You need to iterate through each object and combine them into a single object.

Comment: Just use `Object.assign({}, ...my_array)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reduce` with spreading - you can't map an array to an object. Spreading also allows for multiple properties in each object.

```
var new_array = my_array.reduce((a, c) => ({ ...a, ...c }), {});
```

You could also use `Object.fromEntries` after `flatMap`ping the `entries`:

```
var new_array = Object.fromEntries(my_array.flatMap(Object.entries));
```